# Auto complete all orders within magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status

I need to auto invoice/ship/complete all orders within our store. This is an internal store and we do not require payment however products DO have a price.

Is there a method to auto complete these orders?

Comment: Your internal store is a Magento store?

Comment: Yes, We needed to use magento for integration with another platform.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding an observer on the `sales_order_place_after` event. Below is a very simple example that you could probably build on.

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="vendor_module_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceAfter" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Observer/SalesOrderPlaceAfter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory;

class SalesOrderPlaceAfter extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
{
  protected $_invoiceService;

  protected $_objectManager;

  protected $_shipmentFactory;

  public function __construct(
    InvoiceService $invoiceService,
    ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
  ) {
    $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_shipmentFactory = $shipmentFactory;
  }

  public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $transactionSave = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction::class);

    if($order->canInvoice()) {
      $invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);

      $invoice->register();
      $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

      $transactionSave->addObject($order)
        ->addObject($invoice);
    }

    if($order->canShip()) {
      $shipment = $this->_shipmentFactory->create($invoice->getOrder());
      $shipment->register();

      if($shipment) {
        $transactionSave->addObject($shipment);
      }
    }

    $transactionSave->save();
  }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Vendor_Module',
  __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work [Auto Invoice and Shipment](https://github.com/sohelrana09/module-auto-invoice-shipment)

Comment: How would I install this?

Comment: @BenH download and extract it. finally paste it to respected directory. then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

Comment: So this would just be placed into the root directory of my magento store?

Comment: @BenH see [Folder Structure](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html)

Comment: @BenH have you tried?

Comment: Currently not on this project. Will try shortly. Thank you :)